# $k_e$ (constant of Coulomb force) is sometimes seen in calculations for atomic radii and sometimes not

Tags: electromagnetism, units, coulombs-law, physical-constants, unit-conversion

One of our formula for radius of atom was $\frac{n^2h^2}{4\pi^2me^2}$.

And another one was,

$\frac{n^2h^2}{4\pi^2me^2K}$.

For hydrogen,

Why $k_e$ is sometimes included and sometimes excluded ?

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is written using [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) while the second is written using [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units). Either is a perfectly valid way to write down the equation provided you make sure to stick to whatever system of units you are using.